# What collection method should I use?

Tags: vb.net

I have a text file and it looks like this

```
defabot:3215
defatank:2985
ludditus:29
compensate:355
moobot:805
maxi292003:63
doctorbarzhal:19
plaanz:4
manguuu:51
atntpc:19
immortalsofthemist:18
```

I'm loading this list when my application opens, splitting the name from number and populating a listview control with it. I want to maintain the list in memory for my entire project to use and manipulate.

I need the numbers associated with the name so when I search for the name I know how many points they have. What is the most efficient/easiest way to accomplish this?

Thank you.

Comment: Dictionary(Of String, Integer).

Comment: Is the second item *always* an integer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Dictionary(Of String, Integer)`. Here is an example:

```
Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
For Each s As String In IO.File.ReadAllLines("filename")
  Dim a() As String = s.Split(":"c)
  Dim userName As String = a(0)
  Dim userPoints As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(a(1))
  dict.Add(userName, userPoints)
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

The most efficient way is to use a `Dictionary(Of String, Int32)`:

```
Dim dict As Dictionary(Of String, Int32) = IO.File.ReadLines(path).
    Select(Function(line) line.Split(":"c)).
    ToDictionary(Function(split) split(0), Function(split) Int32.Parse(split(1)))
```

You get the value by it's key:

```
Dim ludditus As Int32 = dict("ludditus")
```